# Re-planting on Shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, agriculture

If a plant was uprooted, is it considered a Melachah of planting to re-soil it on Shabbath?  The simplest example would probably be that a child pulled a plant out of its pot on, or immediately before, Shabbath, and you want to save it.

Comment: [Kind of the opposite of this question.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23088/5)

Comment: See [_Rashi_ s.v. "_Kulan m'lacha achas hen_"](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=269). That said, I don't know about the case where sufficient soil to survive is transported with the detached plant (a common case), so I'm not answering.

Comment: @msh210, thanks. I thought it sounded familiar from Daf Yomi when I was thinking through the question. I'm still not sure how to answer it, though, with regard to my specific case.